# Is it true that $(A^{1/2})^T = (A^T)^{1/2}$ for positive definite matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I'm currently working on a proof in which the term $(A^{1/2})^T$ for some positive definite matrix A $(m \times n)$ is present. Manipulating the term into $(A^{T})^{1/2}$ would greatly benefit me, but is it generally true? A simple reasoning shows
\begin{equation}
A^{1/2} = B \iff A = BB
\end{equation}
and thus
\begin{equation}
A^{1/2} = B \implies (A^{1/2})^{T} = B^T
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A^T = (BB)^T = B^TB^T \implies (A^T)^{1/2} = B^T
\end{equation}
But is this enough to establish that $(A^{1/2})^T = (A^T)^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is completely correct.

Comment: How exactly do you define $A^{1/2}$? For $m=n$ there can be more than one matrix that squares to $A$, and for $m\ne n$ I don't see how it can work at all.

Comment: If $A$ is $m \times n$ with $m \neq n$, then it cannot be positive semidefinite. Also, the square root (as applied to positive semdefinite matrices) is only guaranteed to exist and be positive semidefinite if $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: If $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, then $A^{1/2}$ (which under the usual definition is the symmetric positive definite square root of $A$) will also be symmetric and positive definite. It is **not** true, however, that any matrix $B$ satisfying $B^2 = A$ will be symmetric.

Comment: Ah, I see. Suppose i relax the condition of positive definite and let $m \neq n$, is the square root ill-defined whenever we define it to be $A^{1/2} = B$ such that $A = BB$

Comment: @Maurice: The only way that you can write $A=BB$ is if $B$ is a square matrix (because otherwise the matrix product is not defined). And then $A$ is also a square matrix of the same dimension. For square matrices, $A=BB$ does not generally have an unique solution (to start with, if $B$ is a solution, $-B$ is, too). So you have to add a rule which of the matrices is your square root.